# Public vs Private AttachedProperties

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, attached-properties, attachedbehaviors

Where does it make sense to have `AttachedProperties` as `private` vs `public`?
Usually it is define as (example):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = 
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Command",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(Click),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnSetCommandCallback));
```

But I have also seen examples where some properties are `private static readonly...`

What are the consequences if I change the above `CommandProperty` to `private` now? It seems to be still available in my XAML intellisense if I do that. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that you won't be able to access the `DependencyProperty` from outside of the class. This can make sense if the static Get and Set methods are private as well,  *(in an attached behavior where you need to store some behavior local data for example)* but not otherwise (and I don't think I've ever seen this with public Get and Set).

An example of when you want to use the `DependencyProperty` is `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`. With a public `DependencyProperty` you can do the following

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor de =
    DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Click.CommandProperty, typeof(Button));

de.AddValueChanged(button1, delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Some logic..
});
```

But if the `DependencyProperty` is private, the above code won't work.

However, the following will work fine for both a public and private `DependencyProperty` *(if the static Get and Set methods are public)* since the owner class can access the private `DependencyProperty`. This also goes for Bindings and values set through Xaml where `GetValue` and `SetValue` are called directly.

```
Click.SetCommand(button, ApplicationCommands.Close);
ICommand command = Click.GetCommand(button);
```

If you look through the framework you will notice that all of the public attached properties have a public `DependencyProperty`, for example `Grid.RowProperty` and `Storyboard.TargetNameProperty`. So if the attached property is public, use a public `DependencyProperty`

Comment: What if it the attached behavior is databound in our xaml, and is defined as private? Does the xaml makes the calls to the static Get and Set methods?

Comment: Values set through Binding or Xaml will call `GetValue` and `SetValue` directly so they will still work fine for a private `DependencyProperty`. A public getter and setter is still required to be able to find it though